# "bundle install" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle, gemfile

I'm using the "ruby on rails by example tutorial" (screencasts) by Michael Hartl and I'm getting some errors during the third lesson (sample app) while trying to do "bundle install".

I changed the Gemfile as shown in the tutorial, as shown in the website(the updated one), and even tried the final Gemfile for this tutorial. Every time I get a different error that something couldn't been install, and the bundle installation could not continue.

At first it said it about 'nokogiri', then 'json', and now 'bcrypt'. This did not happen when I did the first app and the demo app. maybe because now I tried added the rspec? I don't want to continue the tutorial without adding it to the Gemfile, because it sounds important.

I'm running osx lion 10.7.2, rails version 3.0.1.

Copying Gemfile code from comment into original post:

```
source 'rubygems.org'; 

gem 'rails', '3.0.1' 
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3' 

group :development do 
     gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.0.beta.18' 
end 

group :test do 
     gem 'rspec', '2.0.0.beta.18' 
end
```

**update:** I heard from someone that rspec is a gem used on tests, therefore you can't make a rails project without the default test and then change the gemfile. So why in the tutorial he make a "rails new sample_app -T" but afterwords changes the Gemfile so it uses rspec? he says, that they replace each other. that rspec replace the original test, and therefore you need to make a project without the original test. any thoughts on this?

Comment: post some code (i.e. your Gemfile) and the error you get. Without more info's it's hard to understand the problem.

Comment: Without the errors you're getting it's impossible to help--we can't see your terminal!

Comment: source 'rubygems.org'; gem 'rails', '3.0.1' gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3' group :development do gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.0.beta.18' end group :test do gem 'rspec', '2.0.0.beta.18' end 
^ this is the Gemfile code. While bundling I get an error: "An error occured while installing nokogiri (1.5.0), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.0' succeeds before bundling". I have installed nokogiri before. So why is this happening ?

Answer (score 0):

I screwed around with this error for a few hours, then checked the [rspec github](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) page.  Per their instructions, you need to include the path to github.  So I made by Gemfile look like following and it now works:

```
group :development do
  gem "rspec-rails",        :git => "git://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails.git"
  gem "rspec",              :git => "git://github.com/rspec/rspec.git"
  gem "rspec-core",         :git => "git://github.com/rspec/rspec-core.git"
  gem "rspec-expectations", :git => "git://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations.git"
  gem "rspec-mocks",        :git => "git://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks.git"
end

group :test do
  gem "rspec-rails",        :git => "git://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails.git"
  gem "rspec",              :git => "git://github.com/rspec/rspec.git"
  gem "rspec-core",         :git => "git://github.com/rspec/rspec-core.git"
  gem "rspec-expectations", :git => "git://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations.git"
  gem "rspec-mocks",        :git => "git://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks.git"
  gem 'webrat'
end
```

I am using Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.1, RVM 1.10.2, Bundler 1.0.21